# Disable authentication for certain files

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I am trying to disable Apache authentication for certain files, but I don't seem to get it right. This is what I have on .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/home/site/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|png|mp3|js|css|json|xml)$">
    Satisfy any
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks right.  Do you have any `Require valid-user` directives in other sections such as `<VirtualHost>` or `<Location>`, that might take precedence?

Comment: What makes strange is that I don't have any other directive. If I use <FilesMatch "">, authentication gets disabled for all files, but it just doesn't work when I specify the files extensions.

Comment: Case problem?  Your files are named e.g. .jpg and not .JPG, right?